# Disable warnings in TypeScript for generated code

Tags: angular, typescript, openapi, tsconfig, openapi-generator

I use OpenApiTool/OpenApi-Generator-CLI to generate code for models and services based on API. When I start my Angular 9 application then in the console I see warnings for generated files:

> WARNING In file.name.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation, but it
> is unused. Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties
> in your tsconfig

All genarated files are placed in ~/src/app/api-client

How to configure tsconfig.json file to disable such warnings for this path?

Comment: This error is from the Angular CLI, no?

Comment: No, it's when I run "npm run start"

Comment: Well, what does that `npm start` delegate to? I ask because you mention Angular and because TypeScript does not produce such a warning.